# Track user from adwords in my own community

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, tracking

I want to track adwords users, who register to my website.

I want to know which ad was clicked and led to a registration and connect this information to the user.

I could f.e. modify the final URL of each of my ads and append a unique query string arg, f.e. my final URL would look something like this for ad1:

```
https://www.example.com/register?adwords=ad1
```

Then if the user registers I could check for the query arg adwords and save this information. This would work and I would know for ever that this user came from adwords ad1, I could also collect data on how much value that user generates over time.

My question is now, is there already a similar system from google, which I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics can identify traffic source by UTM parameters, referrals, and by GCLID. This latter is related to Google Ads, and if set up correctly, you'll automatically see the campaign data in your Analytics reports as `google / cpc` source and medium. You might want to start setup and verification [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=en).